# How to include resource into css file

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I have a css file which I included into Angular project this way:

```
{
  "styles" : [
        "src/assets/css/style.css"
  ],
}
```

But into the css file other files are loaded like:

```
background: url(src/assets/images/preloader.gif)
background-image: url(src/assets/images/photoswipe-controls.svg);
```

I get error:

```
Can't resolve 'src/assets/images/preloader.gif'
```

What is the proper way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url(assets/images/photoswipe-controls.svg);
```

and your angular.json should have this:

```
"assets": [
   "src/assets"
],
```

Comment: I tried it but I get `Can't resolve 'assets/images/photoswipe-controls.svg'`

Comment: hm.. usually shared styles are in different location, "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ], it could be related.